# Python module subprocess not working with Django running server via Apache

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

I am working on a home automation project, and I want to run certain python codes when going to certain URLs of my Django Webpage. The subprocess.call() line from my Django Views.py works perfectly on my Django development server:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import subprocess

def home():
    subprocess.call(['python','path_to_python_file/python_file.py'])
    html = "<html><h1>Hello World</h1></html>" 
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

But the python script (or whatsoever command line) is not called on my Raspberry with Apache. According to many previous questions I've read, this could either be a SELinux issue or an premission issue (the Django/Apache user and group does not have permission to run commands).

Anyone can give me a hand on how to check whether this is caused by one or the other, and how to either configure SELinux or giving permission to Django/Apache to run commands?

Comment: You might try printing the value of `subprocess.call(...)`. It should return an error code; if `0`, it ran fine (in theory), otherwise, an error occurred.

Comment: Another possibility is that python is not on the path for the shell used by your Django/Apache process.  Instead of `python` in the `subprocess.call` you might try specifying the full path to python on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed if for me was replacing the standard Python executable with the path to the Python executable in the virtual environment, e.g. `/var/www/mysite/venv/bin/python3` instead of `python3`